# trying recursion to print a pattern based on arithematic progression in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am learning recursive function and have been trying to print a pattern based on arithmetic progression. like:
**Input 1:** n = 12, k = 5
**Output 2:** 12, 7, 2, -3, 2, 7, 12
**Input 2:** n = 10, k =2
**Output 2:** 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10.
I am getting a , and **None** at the end. like :- *12, 7, 2, -3, 2, 7, 12, None*
Here is my code.

```
# Reading the inputs
n = int(input())
k = int(input())

# Function
def pattern(n,k):

    if (n == 0 or n < 0): 
        print(n, end = ", ")


    else:
        # First print decreasing order 
        print(n, end = ", ") 
        pattern(n - k, k) 

        # Then print increasing order 
        print(n, end = ", ")  


print (pattern(n,k))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Remove the `print (pattern(n,k))`. `pattern` returns `None` and you're printing it. `pattern(n, k)` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Although @ggorlen's comment fixes your immediate issue (+1), let's try a different approach.  Rather than `print` as you recurse, we'll recursively create the list of numbers you desire, return it and then print it:

```
# Function
def pattern(n, k):

    if n <= 0:
        return [n]

    return [n] + pattern(n - k, k) + [n]

# Reading the inputs
n = int(input())
k = int(input())

print(*pattern(n, k), sep=', ')
```

Besides simplifying the code, you now have the choice of whether to print the result of `pattern()` or pass it along to some other code to manipulate further.

```
> python3 test.py
12
5
12, 7, 2, -3, 2, 7, 12
> python3 test.py
10
2
10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
>
```